# nuxeo service does not start after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, service, upgrade, nuxeo

Hello I have tried to upgrade on my ubuntu machine nuxeo package from 5.9.4 to 5.9.5, however upgrade failed, because nuxeo service cannot be started.

I try to start the service with
nuxeoctl --debug startbg

and this i get (part from where the problem starts)

21:45:44,681 DEBUG [org.nuxeo.launcher.config.ConfigurationGenerator.checkDatabaseConnection(ConfigurationGenerator.java:1649)] Testing URL jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/nuxeo with {user=nuxeo, password=hohsheiC}
21:45:44,711 DEBUG [org.nuxeo.launcher.config.ConfigurationGenerator.verifyInstallation(ConfigurationGenerator.java:1263)] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "nuxeo"
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "nuxeo"

I havent change as far as I know login credentials for "nuxeo" user on my system.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue in Nuxeo Platform 5.9.5 (Fast Track) related to datasource credentials. Please downgrade to 5.9.4 until 5.9.6 is released, or follow [NXP-14781](https://jira.nuxeo.com/browse/NXP-14781) to see if a fix is released before the official 5.9.6.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to manually log in the database using those credentials?

You issue may be caused by a PostgreSQL upgrade which:

- installed another cluster, thus Nuxeo tries to connect on the wrong one,
- a lost configuration (see http://answers.nuxeo.com/questions/7719/why-do-i-get-invalid-username-or-password-after-upgrading-postgresql who had an issue with the `pg_hba.conf` file not being repopulated: not containing an entry for `127.0.0.1` for nuxeo)

Comment: I looked at this and found: pg_hba.conf contains an entry for 127.0.0.1 so this is not the issue. Issue might be the cluster. Currently server is running PostgreSQL 9.1.14. - I can see setup via webmin module. There is no "nuxeo" user only "postgres" admin user. So if you say upgrade installed another cluster, where did the original cluster disappear? How could I found out?

Comment: Each cluster has its own port. Use the `pg_lsclusters` command to list the clusters and `pg_isready` to check their connection status:

    $ pg_lsclusters 
    Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory                  Log file
    9.1 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main    /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
    9.3 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main    /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
    9.3 nuxeodb 5434 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/nuxeodb /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-nuxeodb.log

Comment: yes pg_lsclusters shows 2 clusters: main and nuxeodb, both online. main on port 5432 and nuxeodb on 5433. So I presume nuxeo really tries to connect to the wrong cluster. So what ? rollback nuxeo as Florent suggested?

Comment: Yes it's worth to give a try